# How to use a recovered /svn directory tree with svnserve

Tags: svn, svnserve

Our CentOS svn server had a motherboard failure but we were able to recover the entire /svn directory tree and get it moved to a different box.  Apparently directing svnserve to use that folder as the root of the repository isn't sufficient to allow commits, even though all the user and auth information is contained in the directory tree.  Reads work just fine, but commits fail because of authorization problems.  We tried adding new users with svnadduser and that doesn't work either.  If there's a tool that allows svn to 'inherit' a pre-existing repository from the equivalent of a backup, I haven't found it.

What should I be looking at in order to enable commits?

Comment: Apparently it didn't like the old password file.  I created a new password file, but only the three developers in this building can commit changes.  The ids for everyone else fail.  Remote developers can use my id to commit.  I can't see a difference in the setup between their ids and mine that would cause this.

Comment: Were you serving it via svnserve on the old box?  What does the svnserve.conf file look like?

Comment: No, it was using Apache on that box, but that isn't going to be happening on the temporary.  I don't have the conf file on the computer I'm using to write this...but it pretty much reflects what you see in the docs at Red Bean (directories are different, but that's all).

Comment: We narrowed down one problem to the passwords file not working, and then found out that svnserve only seems to honor the first group entry in the authz file.  Not sure why that is--but we can put everyone on the team into the first group.